# заполнение .row колонками в bootstrap

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

столкнулся с проблемой:

```
<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        </div>

</div>
```

по идее .row должна заполняться блоками слева-направо, даже, если идет переполнение как в данном случае. Но выходит вот так: http://take.ms/OJVhE

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/htwg2t8o/ (bootstrap default) - скорее всего у вас применяются другие стили

Answer (score 1):

У Вас первый блок выше чем второй и третий, места в строке хватает только на три блока, поэтому четвертый сносится на новую и "зацепается" за первый. Задайте одинаковую высоту всем блокам, это решит Вашу проблему

Comment: спасибо, для этого достаточно использовать clearfix